# OpenCV haartraining no xml output

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

After using the following commands and leaving the process to run I don't get a classifier xml output. Could anyone tell me why?

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec positivies.vec -bg negatives.txt 
-numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.99 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 228 -numNeg 350 
-w 640 -h 480 -mode ALL
```

Comment: i spent a good 3/4 weeks getting it to work, its fiddly. does it output anything when you run it? also, your width and height are way too big. the idea is to generally use small dimensions (<30) with the right proportion to your feature. from experience also you need more samples if you want at decent trainer, i used 5k negatives and 1000+ unique photos, not generated through the create samples program.

Comment: No I get no output but I'll try and change a few things you've mentioned and see how it runs overnight

Comment: it should give you output straight away, stuff like how many positive and negative samples it has found from the files

Comment: I get output from the createsamples but not the training,

Comment: could you post the full output please in the question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPw9LDFKwODeDVyenZsbkRwTTg/view?usp=sharing thats my create samples code after changing the image size

I'm trying to train the haarcascade to recognize male faces so I can do gender classificaiton

Comment: and literally nothing when you run the train_cascade? check that all the files you input (positives.vec or whatever) actually have legit data entries in them

Comment: I just used the -show command on the create samples and I have all the images in the vec file

Comment: Hi Chris your advice seems to have done the trick! I'm on training stage 5 now but think I need more samples to get better results thanks!